# Magento 2 How to remove custom attribute at time of uninstalling the module using data patch?

Tags: magento2

Using data patch, created one product attribute. I wants to remove that attribute when extension is unstalled. Generally we are using Uninstall.php but my question was that, how can we uninstall it by using data patch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create Uninstall. php inside setup directory from module directory.
write your logic over there to remove the attribute.
so when you will run
bin/ magento module:uninstall [MODULE NAME]
then your Uninstall script will run and code will be executed.

Comment: Attribute created with data patch is also removed using Uninstall.php ? Is it not possible to create any patch for the same?